# How to only select the nth (42nd) `p` tag with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, keyerror

I wrote a program that saves the page source from `https://www.coinbase.com/price` to `pyt.txt`. How can I parse the price of bitcoin from this text file and have it be printed?

So far, I have learned that the 42nd `p` tag in the page source is the one that holds the price of bitcoin. So, my code to attempt to extract that value and print it is as follows:

```
import bs4
file = open('location/pyt.txt', 'r')

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(file, 'lxml')
for btc in soup.find_all('p'):
    print(btc[41])

file.close()
```

When I run it I get the error:

```
return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 41
```

After many hours of YouTubing and googling it seems that BeautifulSoup would work best but I just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: There are good answers below, but I want to recommend the use on an API. See https://www.coindesk.com/coindesk-api and https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json. This way you are protected if your site changes the format of their page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CSS Selector `p:nth-of-type(42)`, which will select the 42nd `<p>` tag.

```
print(soup.select_one('p:nth-of-type(42)'))
```

Comment: I replaced "for btc in soup.find_all('p'):
    print(btc[41])" with "print(soup.select_one('p:nth-of-type(42)'))" and it returned "None". Do you have any idea what could be the issue as I didn't get any errors, so it seems to be "working".

Comment: @testical Please edit your question with the HTML.

Answer (score -1):

btc is not a list or any other data types its a string
so if you want to access the 41th p tag in this way,  you can append every item to a list then access to the index of the list

Comment: I assumed ('p') would assign all the p tags to "btc" and create a list. Do you know how I should go about creating a list like that?